# Medicine/drug to "get along" with difficult people?

Tags: medications, home-remedies, recreational-drugs, mood-moodiness

This is not a solicitation for medical advice. If I want a medical opinion I know I need to see a doctor.

Are there specific medicines, drugs and/or substances which:

- are legal in the USA without a prescription for adults over 21 years of age; and
- maintain desired effects, and are safe with no serious side effects over the long term, during waking hours for up to one full week (suppose weeks are separated by at least a month)
- have the desired effect of significantly improving one's ability to "deal with" another person that one can't stand being around due to obnoxious mannerisms and behaviors which are not intended to cause offense?

If not - are there any that satisfy the third and either the first or second (but not both) constraints?

Some things that came to mind:
- Alcohol (not completely effective, side effects, hard to conceal)
- Lithium, antidepressants, etc.; do these need a prescription?
- St John's Wort - purportedly a mood elevator, is there evidence it works?
- Etc.

Disclaimer: I understand that getting doped up is not an emotionally healthy way to deal with one's problems. For the purposes of this question, please work under the purely theoretical assumption that this is the only available class of options.

Comment: This is specifically about improving ability to copy with annoyances, such as another person's behaviour? Look into mindfulness and meditation which, while not a drug, meet all three of your requirements (and are free.)

Comment: @KateGregory Thanks for the suggestion - that is actually a really good idea and one I had considered but only briefly. It merits a closer look.